# VS2010 doesn't appear in my apps windows 8

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-8

Mine is a Windows 8 machine. I installed Visual Studio 2012, then went to Microsoft SQL Server 2012. Later I was told to install Visual Studio 2010. 
The first two installs worked great. Got all the neat icons and everything is good. MSVS2010 SP1 got installed successfully.

Now the third install of Visual Studio 2010 is where I am stuck.
I am downloading it from a Microsoft licensed CD. No errors during installation, but it is only installing Microsoft Visual Studio command prompt, X64 Win64 command prompt and Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 documentation. Nothing else. So basically I dunno where to start to fire up the program.

So I went to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7`, `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7` to find the `devenv.exe`. Couldn't find in either of the locations.

Then went to Run and typed devenv.exe, boom VS2010 opens. So I did a Apps search on Windows 8. When I type devenv.exe the only thing I could find there is SQL Server data tools which has a VS2010 icon. Double click this and VS 2010 opens. So my guess is SQL server 2012 needs VS2010 and installed it.

**Questions**:

1. Where is devenv.exe?
2. Why isn't it installing the rest of the stuff?
3. How do I start VS2010?

I don't think double clicking on sql server data tools is the correct way. I want VS2010 to  appear in my Apps just like any other application.  This could be a rather silly question. I did a lot of research and am kinda confused with all these parameters.

Comment: Uninstall everything and start over. Ignore what you were told, and start with Visual Studio 2010, then install the 2012 products. When people tell you to do something ("Later I was told"), make sure you understand what that means and what it might do to your system before you do it. (Voting to close this as "too localized", because it's doubtful anyone else will repeat these same steps to foul up their systems and find this question useful. It's most likely going to only be useful to you personally.) Good luck!

Comment: @kenwhite - this is not isolated. i think it might just be that vs2010 isnt totally compatible with win 8. i have the exact same thing happen on my machine. i'm pretty sure i installed in the right order (vs 10 first then 12).

Comment: @user575219 can you do everything that you need to do in vs10? if so, add the icon for vs10 (ssdt) to your win 8 task bar. that's what i did and that's how i launch vs10.

Comment: @Ken White, all. Thank u. I uninstalled Sql server 2012 and reinstalled it. The only difference I did was delete the Microsoft_corporation folder bcoz it was complaining abt some landing page.exe stuff. Then unistalled VS2012, VS2010. So cleaned it all. Then started with VS2010, VS2012, SQl 2012. It was painful but works now.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Windows 8, if you search for "Visual Studio" in "Start" screen you won't find VS 2010. Instead search for "devenv", it appears.

Searching for "SQL server data tools" also will work.

In 64bit machines, you can find 2010 in

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE

Create a Desktop short cut.

Answer (score 9):

Uninstalling and re installing Visual Studios is not required for the Visual Studio 2010 icon to show up on Windows 8.The Visual Studio 2010 icon is located at C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv. You can add this icon to your task bar or windows desktop and launch Visual Studio 2010. There are two devenv icons in that folder location just select latest one you can find that out by looking at the file properties. The folder path I mentioned above will be different for 64 bit windows machines.

Comment: This worked for me for vs 2008 an 2010. Thanks.  Strange part of this is when I added them to the start screen it actually added them with the wrong program name.  They seemed to add as SQL programs, like SQL Server Manager. They went even named as the same wrong program.  Its like windows 8 just randomly picked the name or a program I had installed and decided to run with it. This happened with 2008 and 2010.  I had to right click then open the containing folder then rename the shortcut accordingly.  Very strange.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason Visual Studio 2010 did not completely load for me, although it said it did. So I went into its folder and selected the setup.exe to run maintenance mode. There I re-installed it. It asked me (this time) to restart my laptop. I did that. Then I was prompted to  update it using the service pack 1 update, via the given link. Then it was ok.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to view:

- In `Win8` or `Win8.1` search for `"devenv.exe"` name it appear and create shortcut in desktop.
- Go to this address on your computer:
  `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe`

and create a shortcut for this file on your desktop.

Answer (score -1):

You have two options here
in windows 8.0 or 8.1 go to run and type'devenv' and then the Visual studio opens up for you.

Else search using the app name and select 'Microsoft Visual studio' from the list of apps installed, right click on the app and select the option 'pin to the start' or 'pin to the task bar'. This creates short cut with the icon of the app handy.